# Linear Regression on Set of Prefixed Variables in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am using the `dummies` package to break a large dataset into a series of dummy variables for further analysis. This is very convenient, but now I'd like to be able to easily run a regression on some variables in my dataframe without explicitly listing 20+ dummy variables.

Is it possible to call these variables into my regression based on prefix? I.E. I have columns: x1100, x1101, x1102, x2200, x2203, x2229 and I want to run a regression on some few predetermined columns, as well as all of x11* where * is a wildcard indicating every column that starts with x11.

Something like:
`model <- lm(price ~ month + weather + df[x11*], data=df)` ?

After much googling I haven't been able to figure out if there's a way to do this yet. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: My question is not a duplicate, as I'm not using as.formula and I don't think that's relevant to solving my problem.

Comment: Would making a vector of the column names you want included, subsetting the data to only include the relevant data and then using something like `lm(price ~ ., data=yoursubset)` work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does as.formula only work inside lm() inside with()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659510/why-does-as-formula-only-work-inside-lm-inside-with)

Comment: You can use regex to extract the relevant variable names as a string, and then use `as.formula` to convert that string into a formula which you can pass to `lm`